# Filter condition BIRT - equal

Tags: filter, report, equals, birt

I'm trying to create a filter condition, to show all results when this field is equal to 30 OR to 31.

I'm using this, but this is only showing for '30'.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression in brackets on the right side of the `Equals to` is evaluated first. `('30' || '31')` returns always `'30'` (try it in a JavaScript evaluator) so `equals to` can always compare to only one value.

You need to place your expression in the left side (click the `fx`) like this:

```
row["agg::agg_field_id"] == '30' || row["agg::agg_field_id"] == '31'
```

Than you replace the `Equals to` from the drop down with `is True` and you are done.